# Gradle's Scala Zinc compiler performance issues

Tags: scala, gradle

We've just upgraded Gradle from 2.10 to 3.0 and are having major performance issues with Scala compilation on clean builds after switching to the Zinc compiler from the ant-based compiler.

Assembling our project, which currently is a multiproject setup of about 50 subprojects with mixed Java and Scala sources, previously took about 1.5mins when running in parallel mode (about an extra minute if not run in parallel) locally on my laptop. It's now around 7(!) mins in parallel mode and 5 mins in "normal" mode.

We've attempted to  adjust the memory settings of the compile process, but without any success.

Are there other ways to speed things up?

Thanks!
/d

Comment: This might be a good question to pose in the Gradle user forum. Since this sounds like a performance regression, I'd suggest the bugs forum https://discuss.gradle.org/c/bugs

Comment: Posted about it int he discussion forum, but as I can find no information really regarding the decision of actually removing the ant-based compiler, I'll probably report it as a bug like you say.